# Using TempData outside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm making a `ControllerFactory`. In this class, I want to have access, in the method `CreateController`, to the `TempData` variable that is accessible in all controllers.

```
public class ControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        //TODO :IoC implementation or call comes here.
        return null;
    }

    public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
      var disposable = controller as IDisposable;
      if (disposable != null)
      {
        disposable.Dispose();
      }
    }

    public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        //HERE I WANT TO HAVE ACCESS TO THE TempData
    }

    public SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
    }
}
```

Notes: Before the code reaches the controller when a page it is called, the fuction `CreateController` present int this code it's reaches.

Any Idea How I can access to the `TempData` in the `CreateController` method?

Comment: I don't think TempData is what you think it is.  TempData is a temporary dictionary that is only good for one read (it deletes itself after you access it once).  I struggle to find any useful usage of TempData in a controller factory, since the data would then no longer be there for the controller/view.  And, more importantly, if the user presses F5, the data will be gone so the controller factory won't have it anymore to re-render the page.  TempData is basically only useful for short notification messages and the like, which don't need to be re-rendered if the page is refreshed.

Comment: I make you a example, for better understanding. If the TempaData["object"] != null i want build the controller1, if not, i want to build the default controller. So, to doing that i need to have access to the temp data in my ControllerFactory. Note that the TempData["object"] can be field by any controller.

Comment: Ok, but when you do that TempData["object"] != null, it will delete it, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes I know and it is what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core MVC sources they do this

```
var tempDataDictionaryFactory = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITempDataDictionaryFactory>();
var tempDataDictionary = tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context);
if (tempDataDictionary.TryGetValue(MyClaims.Claim1, out object value))
{
    return (string)value;
}
```

Where context is HttpContext

Which works perfect for me

Comment: In case you need to write to TempData, you will also have to call [TempDataDictionary.Save()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.itempdatadictionary.save)